# Can't resolve '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css'?

Tags: reactjs, blueprint

I have imported

```
import '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css';
```

but it gives an error like below

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css' in 'D:\REACT\react-firebase\src'
```

its true its not in project src its in mode modules package

why this happen how can I fix this

Comment: What's the name of the package ? Why do you have a `@` in it ? Is it the namespace ?

Comment: becauser documantation like that if I remove that also it not change anyhing getting the same error

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
import '@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css';
```

Instead of

```
import '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while trying to use the [react-mosaic-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mosaic-component) package. I had to install [blueprintjs](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint) core & icons like so:

> `npm install @blueprintjs/core @blueprintjs/icons`